# Finding certain values from a dictionary as an input to a constructor python

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have the following code:

```
# constructor
def __init__(self, dict):

    # Inputs
    harvesting_time = 16 # hours
    recovery_rate = 90 # %
    unit_throughput = 93.63 # kg/annum/unit
    cost_per_unit = 275000 # $
    electricity = 0.0000331689825  # kWh/kg/unit
    energy_cost = 10.41  # cent/kWh
    labor_cost = 1777000  # $/annum
    concentration = 100 # g/L

    throughput = dict.get("output(kg/annum)",default=None)  # kg/annum
    carbon = dict.get("carbon",default=None)
    nitrogen = dict.get("nitrogen",default=None)
    carbohydrates = dict.get("carbohydrates",default=None)
    proteins = dict.get("proteins",default=None)
    lipids = dict.get("lipids",default=None)
```

The idea is that another class is suppose to generate a dictionary of values that this constructor takes as an input and searches the values for in order to do certain calculations. However, whenever I run my program (externally), I get the following error.

throughput = dict.get("output(kg/annum)",default=None)  # kg/annum

TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments

Could someone explain what this error means and how I can circumvent it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just removes `default=None` in all `dict.get`, you will have exact same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
throughput = dict.get("output(kg/annum)",default=None)  # kg/annum
```

Don't use the keyword "default" when specifying the default value.

```
throughput = dict.get("output(kg/annum)", None)  # kg/annum
```

Actually, since the default is None by default, you don't have to provide a second argument at all.

```
throughput = dict.get("output(kg/annum)")  # kg/annum
```